# How to get real time bounding rectagle in Firefox using UIAutomation?

Tags: firefox, ui-automation

Here's the code.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <UIAutomation.h>

IUIAutomation* p_iui;
IUIAutomationElement* p_fcs_element;

AllocConsole();
CoInitialize(NULL);
CoCreateInstance(
        __uuidof(CUIAutomation),
        NULL,
        CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_PPV_ARGS(&p_iui));

while(true)
{
    Sleep(1000);

    p_iui->GetFocusedElement(&p_fcs_element);
    RECT r;
    p_fcs_element->get_CurrentBoundingRectangle(&r);
    _cprintf("Rect: %d,%d,%d,%d\n", r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom);
}
CoUninitialize();
FreeConsole();
```

I want to get the bounding rectangle of the focused input control per second, when moving the browser app.
This works fine with Internet Explorer, Edge and Chrome.
e.g. Chrome
[image: using Chrome]
When I am using Firefox, the url input control also works fine, but the input control within web page (such as search input control in [Google](https://www.google.com)) keeps returning the same bounding rectangle.
Firefox
[image: Firefox]
Should I change some Firefox settings, or is this just an issue or bug?
Thank you.